# Problem downloading Sift workstation on VMware workstation 16 pro

Tags: sift, sift-tool

Newbie here. For education purposes I needed to download the OVA file of Sans Sift workstation to run on my VMware workstation 16 pro. It downloaded but never really open up. It ended up with a black screen with a blinking cursor. Ran it again and it is the same again. Uninstall and install again same outcome. Anyone encountered something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may still be able to login - press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> (or maybe <kbd>F1</kbd>). Login at the prompts and then type the command `startx`

This should hopefully give you the gui.

Answer (score 0):

Just as above, I was able to get the login screen to show up by pressing alt f1, altf2 then alt f1 again, so i don't know which one really worked.  Anyway once I logged in I was able to use apt-get update and then i used apt-get dist-upgrade, and once that was complete I restarted the VM and the login screen appeared and once logged in, the Ubuntu GUI was there and it has been working ever since.